# Bitmap resource not found on Android 1.5 platform AVD

Tags: android

I have a bitmap that I want to display in my Android app. This works fine for platforms with version number greater than 1.5 but not for 1.5. When executing the line below an exception is thrown stating that the resource couldn't be found.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mApplicationContext.getResources(), R.drawable.arrow);
```

I have put the bitmap in all density-folders (hdpi, mdpi, ldpi) and scaled them according to the documentation (the mdpi-bitmap is 25x25 pixels and the ldpi-bitmap size 75% of the mdpi-bitmap size and the hdpi-bitmap size 150% of the mdpi-bitmap size).
Any idea what is wrong here?
Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding /res/drawable directory and copy /res/drawable-midp pictures to it.

Android 1.5 [does not support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility) resolution independence.

Comment: Splendid! I did search the documentation but missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android 1.5 does not have all the desity dependent folders. They started those from 1.6.

What you want to do is put the medium density drawables in a folder named 'drawable' and it will work. Also note that after you do that you do not need drawable-mdpi directory any more as it is a redundancy.